# PHPMailer why i get connection timeout error?

Tags: php, exchange-server, phpmailer

In the company I work for we use microsoft exchange server and ofcourse ms outlook to send and recieve email.

on andriod we use exchange application as following to access our mail.

[image]

I am trying to use the following code to send emails IN php:

```
 require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 $mail = new PHPMailer;

 $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

 $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
 $mail->Host = 'mail.dom-domain.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
 $mail->Username = 'username';                 // SMTP username
 $mail->Password = 'password123';                           // SMTP password
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
 $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

 $mail->setFrom('username@dom-domain.com', 'Mailer');
 $mail->addAddress('recname@yahoo.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
 //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
 $mail->addReplyTo('username@dom-domain.com', 'Information');
 //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
 //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

 //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
 //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
 $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

 $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject tls587';
 $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body tls587 <b>in bold!</b>';
 $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients tls587';

 if(!$mail->send()) {
     echo 'Message could not be sent.';
     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
     echo 'Message has been sent';
 }
```

but the page loads alot and I get this error:

> 2017-04-02 13:13:45 Connection: opening to mail.dom-domain.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2017-04-02 13:14:48 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to mail.dom-domain.com:587 (Connection timed out) [/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/ml/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php line 294] 2017-04-02 13:14:48 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 2017-04-02 13:14:48 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: As it says - it's having trouble connecting to your mail server. It may be because your ISP blocks outbound SMTP. Read the troubleshooting guide that the error message links to.

Comment: yes I got that, but how come i can connect using a third party app on android if the outbound SMTP is blocked?

Comment: Because it is blocked on the network which your server is on, but not the one that your phone is on. It's down to the networks, not the client code. If PHPMailer was running on your phone, it would work.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. But I used the same code on gmail smtp server and it works. Where exactly the difference?

Comment: You didn't say that. That sounds like you have a local connectivity problem to your mail server. If you use the tests described in the guide, it will show you where the problem is.

Comment: Please keep noted that you are mostly using MS ActiveSync on your device when using MS Exchange (to sync ToDos, eMails, Calendar, Contacts, ...) and not a IMAP/SMTP with CALDav connection like for Google Mail...

Answer (score 0):

*Keep noted that on your Android device you are mostly using Microsoft Active Sync via port 443. You do NOT use a native SMTP connection here via port 587 (which would be used via IMAP/POP3). The same is true for a plain Outlook connection where MAPI or MAPI over HTTP/Outlook Anywhere is used. Both do not use a native SMTP connection here and might be the reason why it isn´t working. BUT on your GMail Account you are mostly using IMAP as this isn´t an Exchange Server which support Microsoft Active Sync.*

It might therefore possible that your Exchange Administrator didn´t configured the SMTP Connector for external Authenticated connections for Outlook users as this isn´t needed in your case and therefore disabled for security reasons. As you didn´t specify if you are the Exchange Administrator and which version you are using its not easy to give you a how to here. So instead of that, you should follow these howtos here from Microsoft:

- [Controlling SMTP Relaying with Microsoft Exchange](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277329.aspx)
- [Configure authenticated SMTP settings for POP3 and IMAP4 clients in Exchange 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg298947(v=exchg.160).aspx)

If you aren´t an Microsoft Exchange Administrator you can try to send emails via the Microsoft Exchange Webservices (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600292(v=exchg.150).aspx)). However as said above, the Exchange Administrator might run a special configuration here to secure the environment.